# Do you get the war loot bonus if you get 1 star on a base that someone else has alread 3 starred?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have been playing clash of clans, and I want to 1 star a farming person in war and get a ton of loot. (I can't do any better to anyone else). My clan says to wait until the near end of the war, but idk if I will still get loot if someone already got at least 1 star.

Comment: @JK01: The OP explicitly states that he cannot improve the clans war standing. If the only targets that have stars available are ones that are much higher in level than what the player can successfully attack, then the clan actually *benefits* from that player earning as much loot as possible because it will help improve that player. If you expect your 25th player to attack their 12th player because their 13-25 are already 3-starred, then your clan, as a whole, won't benefit because the player will not earn as much loot as he could have by not attacking a more reasonable target.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes. You do.

War loot is only awarded when you successfully attack a base.

#### But wait. I didn't tell you enough!

Regardless of the current high score (best attack) of the base, as long as you manage to 1-star it (win the attack), you get the bonus... Even if it's already 3-started.

However, the star you gain **does not** count towards the score as it have already been earned (unless you beat that score of course).
Doing this only helps you if your clan is already winning, and the opponents have no chance at winning, as it is practically simply wasting your attack.

As usual, losing the war only awards 40% of the bonus.

Comment: This answer could be improved by also answering the question of whether that star counts for the war hero achievement. (I have no idea)

Comment: @JohnFx Why don't you edit it in? - After all, you've got access to unmoderated editing (as in now review queues)...

Comment: Because I don't know the answer

Comment: @JohnFx Then please ask that as another question. Having this information here would be irrelevant since the OP wasn't asking for it.

Comment: So after war you either get 40% or 100% of the loot, their are no other possibilities?

Comment: @Celeritas Well, both sides only get 30% if it's a draw.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

But always ask for the leader and co-leader's permission before doing so. Members of the clan are expected to cooperate, help each other, work as a team, and win the war and winning the loot should be the last thing in your mind.

This is the problem I always face with new members of the clan.

Put greed on a leash, at least until the win is certain..

Happy clashing!!! Have a nice day!

Comment: He is not asking for the reason to attack. Try to answer to the point. He needs info whether he gets the loot bonus  even if he gets 1 star from a 3 starred base. This situation comes to play when  all the enemy bases has been 3 starred and the players still got their attacks left. The player can't just leave their their attacks because in doing so would be dumb. If you manage to 1 star a 3 starred base which is high up your recommended target you get a handsome bonus.